# Passing paramater to subquery in MS Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to get this query to select every `department_id` from my `departments` table, and then pass those values (there are about 30 or so) onto a sub query like so

> ```
> SELECT Count(problems.id) AS Problems, 
> departments.dname AS Company, 
> departments.department_id AS CompanyID,
> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM problems WHERE problems.status BETWEEN 1 AND 8) AS totalopentickets, 
> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM problems WHERE status = 100) AS totalclosedtickets, 
> (SELECT COUNT(problems.department) FROM problems WHERE problems.status = 100 AND problems.department = CompanyID) AS departmentclosed, 
> (SELECT COUNT(problems.department) FROM problems WHERE problems.status BETWEEN 1 AND  8 AND problems.department = CompanyID) AS departmentopen
> FROM problems 
> INNER JOIN departments ON problems.department = departments.department_id
> GROUP BY departments.dname, departments.department_id
> ORDER BY Count(problems.id) DESC;
> ```

The idea is that it will grab all those values (1,2, 3 etc) then perform the sub query

> (SELECT COUNT(problems.department) FROM problems WHERE problems.status BETWEEN 1 AND  8 AND problems.department = CompanyID)

With each of those values. This works in MySQL but I am unsure of how to get it to work in Access. Each time it asks me for a parameter then when I do I only get the values for the one parameter value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this just now by not using the alias but instead using the table and field name, like so

```
SELECT Count(problems.id) AS Problems, 
departments.dname AS Company, 
departments.department_id AS CompanyID,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM problems WHERE problems.status BETWEEN 1 AND 8) AS totalopentickets, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM problems WHERE status = 100) AS totalclosedtickets, 
(SELECT COUNT(problems.department) FROM problems WHERE problems.status = 100 AND problems.department = departments.department_id) AS departmentclosed, 
(SELECT COUNT(problems.department) FROM problems WHERE problems.status BETWEEN 1 AND  8 AND problems.department = departments.department_id) AS departmentopen
FROM problems 
INNER JOIN departments ON problems.department = departments.department_id
GROUP BY departments.dname, departments.department_id
ORDER BY Count(problems.id) DESC;
```